# Generate unique nickname for user automatically

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I need to generate unique nickname that contains user's first name and some random word of predefined set of adjectives. There are collisions may occur due to the non-unique combination of the user's first name and an adjective. How can collisions be avoided? I want to add incremental postfix in the generated sequence like `amused-alex`, `amused-alex-1`, `amused-alex-2`, ..., `amused-alex-n`.

My idea is to create additional table that containing all names that already used:

| nickname | count |
| --- | --- |
| amused-alex | 2 |
| bionic-john | 1 |

So the next collision of `amused-alex` would have nickname like `amused-alex-3`. Perhaps there are some more optimal solutions for solving such problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe all you need is a `serial` columns in order to order the nickname aliases.

Example:

```
create table users_test(nickname varchar,nick_id serial);
insert into users_test values ('amused-alex');
insert into users_test values ('amused-alex');
insert into users_test values ('good-joe');
insert into users_test values ('good-joe');
insert into users_test values ('good-joe');
```

Now `users_test` contains five rows

```
  nickname   | nick_id 
-------------+---------
 amused-alex |       1
 amused-alex |       2
 good-joe    |       3
 good-joe    |       4
 good-joe    |       5
(5 rows)
```

And with the following query you can generate always different nicknames.

```
select nickname, nick_id, nickname ||'-' ||rank() over (partition by nickname order by nick_id asc) nickname_unique from users_test;
  nickname   | nick_id | nickname_unique 
-------------+---------+-----------------
 amused-alex |       1 | amused-alex-1
 amused-alex |       2 | amused-alex-2
 good-joe    |       3 | good-joe-1
 good-joe    |       4 | good-joe-2
 good-joe    |       5 | good-joe-3
(5 rows)
```

The query is using the `RANK` function over the `nick_id` serial column. This ensures there will never be collisions.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to insert a record with unique nickname via `rank()` clause?

Comment: @savovit902 . . . Note that `serial` columns are no longer recommended in Postgres.  Instead, use `generated always as identity`.